# How to change multiple cursors system-wide in Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to replace multiple system cursors using `SetSystemCursor`. My first call changes the cursor of `OCR_NORMAL` but the subsequent calls are not working.

```
HCURSOR hWaitCur = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT);
HCURSOR cursorCopy = CopyCursor(hWaitCur);

SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_NORMAL); // This works

// Not working
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_APPSTARTING); 
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_CROSS);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_HAND);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_HELP);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_IBEAM); 
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_NO);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_WAIT);
```

What would be the correct way to update multiple system cursors at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsystemcursor) (emphasize by me):

> **The system destroys hcur** by calling the DestroyCursor function. Therefore, hcur cannot be a cursor loaded using the LoadCursor function. To specify a cursor loaded from a resource, copy the cursor using the CopyCursor function, then pass the copy to SetSystemCursor.

So you need to copy it before each call:

```
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_NORMAL);
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_APPSTARTING); 
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_CROSS);
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_HAND);
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_HELP);
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_IBEAM); 
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_NO);
SetSystemCursor(CopyCursor(hWaitCur), OCR_WAIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

Since `SetSystemCursor` destroys `cursorCopy` after setting, there is a need to recopy `hWaitCur` for every call.

```
/* ... */

HCURSOR cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_APPSTARTING);

cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_NORMAL);

cursorCopy = CopyCursor(cursor);
SetSystemCursor(cursorCopy, OCR_CROSS);

/* ... */
```